# Change background color of JavaFX Chart

Tags: css, javafx, charts, styles, background-color

I want to set the background color to some JavaFX charts (`LineChart` and `BarChart`).

Tried this:

```
chart.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ffbd05");
```

and

```
chart.setStyle("-fx-bar-fill: #ffbd05");
```

... but no effect.

Comment: This will be easier with a CSS file as you need to target the substructure of the chart. See the [Chart](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#chart) and [XYChart](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#xychart) sections of the _JavaFX CSS Reference Guide_. Also, to help visualize things, you can inspect the scene graph with _Scenic View_ and/or the CSS Analyzer of _Scene Builder_.

Comment: @Slaw Thanks for your awesome advice! The CSS Analyzer was completely new to me, its a very handy tool. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In case is useful for somebody. Think this may help:

```
chart.lookup(".chart-plot-background").setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent;");
```

More on chart styling: https://news.kynosarges.org/2017/05/14/javafx-chart-coloring/

Answer (score 0):

add it to your css file:

```
.bar-chart .chart-content .chart-plot-background {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```